# Removing Interior and exterior polygons using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I have a polygon layer that has donuts and also exterior parts.
Using python, I am able to get access to each part, but  what I would like to know is using arcpy, once I have a part, how do I go about deleting all the vertices for that part.
This is what I have
[image]

and this is what I would like to end up with
[image]

Comment: If you can safely assume the first multi-part ring is the largest, then you could rewrite the shape with the first ring.  Unfortunately, that's one of those ass-u-me assumptions that tend to backfire.  Anyway you do it, you'll be using a cursor to either update the current shape or (preferably) inserting a new row into a disimproved feature class with the trucated geometry.

Comment: You should have a look at this [q&a](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134066/how-to-find-if-polygon-has-a-hole-using-field-calculator-in-arcgis/134078#134078).

Comment: Even though it's not really an arcpy solution, the [Eliminate Polygon Part](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Eliminate_Polygon_Part/00170000005q000000/) tool does exactly what you want. It requires an Advanced license.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete entire geometry parts without having to delete each vertex. Refer to this page on python access to shapes and interior rings from [ArcGIS Help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm#GUID-9FC74E09-898D-4A5E-9A07-76CD911C2AC6)  There is also a GP tool that will remove the doughnut holes. It is on [GitHub](https://github.com/bnadler/RemoveInteriorRingsGP)

As far as deleting parts of a multi-part feature, you will need a strategy for identifying the part you want to delete. Size (absolute or relative) or # of vertices are options, as is a spatial relationship to other features (intersect with FC to see if it overlaps anything). Provide more detail in the question and perhaps some ideas will pop up...

Answer (score 1):

```
# UNION WITH NO GAPS FILL TO FILL THE RINGS  
union_polygons = os.path.join("in_memory", "union_polygons")
arcpy.Union_analysis(polygon_feature, union_polygons, gaps="NO_GAPS")

# DISSOLVE SINGLE PART  
dissolve_polygons = os.path.join("in_memory", "dissolve_polygons")
arcpy.Dissolve_management(union_polygons, dissolve_polygons, multi_part="SINGLE_PART")

# JOIN FIELDS TO SINGLE PART FEATURE WITH NO RINGS
spatial_join_polygons = os.path.join("in_memory", "spatial_join_polygons")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(
    dissolve_polygons, polygon_feature, spatial_join_polygons, join_type="KEEP_COMMON"
  )
```