# Eliminating Polygon Parts with ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder and Basic Level License

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, basic-license-level, eliminate

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0 Basic.

I'm trying to eliminate holes in an polygon-layer within a certain extent by using ModelBuilder. The generalization-tool (Eliminate Polygon Parts) isn't licensed with Basic...

I'm trying my best but it doesn't work. Anyone have an idea of how to generate polygons within the existing ones to select them afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to use advanced field calculator within your model, [this expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134066/how-to-find-if-polygon-has-a-hole-using-field-calculator-in-arcgis) will help to locate polygons with holes.

This one:

```
def outRing(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 pgon=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 return pgon
#------
outRing( !Shape!)
```

will eliminate hole(s). If data stored in gdb, you need to start editing session.

Works on single part polygons only!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the [Union](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) tool, setting the 'gaps' parameter to false. But then the resulting polygons would need the attributes. In this case, I would see if using either the Spatial Join ot Dissolve tools would be best to populate the attributes of those 'gap' polygons.