# Finding how many holes are in polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, geometry

I have many polygons, and I want to know how many holes are in the polygon using field calculator. Like this polygon that has three holes.

[image]

Comment: See @Hornbydd answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134066/how-to-find-if-polygon-has-a-hole-using-field-calculator-in-arcgis tiny modification of the script will do.

Comment: In QGIS, there is a function `num_interior_rings( $geometry)` that you could use directly in the field calculator to get the number of interior rings/holes. Isn't there anything similar in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ArcGIS `Polygon` objects can have one or more parts, with each part containing one or more subparts (rings).

[image: Six polygons]

There are a number of ways to extract the number of "holes" (interior subparts), but the easiest is to subtract the number of parts from the number of subparts.  While there is a `Polygon.partCount` property, there isn't a `subpartCount`, but converting the `Polygon` to `Polyline` boundaries will generate the subparts, which can be counted.  Thus the equation is:

```py
Polygon.boundary().partCount - Polygon.partCount
```

We can see this work with the following script:

```py
import arcpy

def num_holes(poly):
    return poly.boundary().partCount - poly.partCount

wkts = [
    'POLYGON ((0 0, 9 0, 9 9, 0 9, 0 0))',
    'POLYGON ((0 0, 9 0, 9 9, 0 9, 0 0),(2 2, 2 4, 4 4, 4 2, 2 2))',
    'POLYGON ((0 0, 9 0, 9 9, 0 9, 0 0),(2 2, 2 4, 4 4, 4 2, 2 2),(7 1, 7 8, 8 8, 8 1, 7 1))',
    'MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 5 0, 5 9, 0 9, 0 0)),((6 0, 9 0, 9 9, 6 9, 6 0)))',
    'MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 5 0, 5 9, 0 9, 0 0),(2 2, 4 2, 4 4, 2 4, 2 2)),((6 0, 9 0, 9 9, 6 9, 6 0)))',
    'MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 5 0, 5 9, 0 9, 0 0),(2 2, 4 2, 4 4, 2 4, 2 2)),((6 0, 9 0, 9 9, 6 9, 6 0),(7 1, 7 8, 8 8, 8 1, 7 1)))']

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
for i,wkt in enumerate(wkts,start=1):
    shp = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt,sr)
    print("i={:d} parts={:d} subparts={:d} holes={:d}".format(
            i,shp.partCount,shp.boundary().partCount,num_holes(shp)))
```

Which displays:

```
i=1 parts=1 subparts=1 holes=0
i=2 parts=1 subparts=2 holes=1
i=3 parts=1 subparts=3 holes=2
i=4 parts=2 subparts=2 holes=0
i=5 parts=2 subparts=3 holes=1
i=6 parts=2 subparts=4 holes=2
```

In CalculateField, the syntax would be:

```py
!shape!.boundary().partCount - !shape!.partCount
```

Comment: While revisiting geometry topology to respond to an earlier comment, I came across an uncommon but interesting situation where a given visual shape has two different implementations (_at least two I figured out_), and those different implementations have many properties in common but not all, including number of holes.  For example an inverted polygon,`'POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 5 10, 5 15, 10 15, 10 10, 15 10, 15 20, 0 20, 0 0))'` , and its donut hole equivalent,`'POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 15 10, 15 20, 0 20, 0 0),(10 10, 5 10, 5 15, 10 15, 10 10))'`.

Comment: Esri topology has a preference, though PostGIS/OGC has a different one.  Within a "valid" geometry, the answer will be right for that system.  I'll poke at that example and address it if I have some insight.

Comment: Esri Check Geometry tool using Esri's rules said both are valid.  Esri Check Geometry using OGC said the inverted was "non simple."  I don't work with PostGIS, but SQL Server IsValidDetailed said both were valid.  I thought SQL Server would be using an OGC validation but I guess not exactly.